# Exclude a directory from find linux

Tags: linux, bash, find

I want to exclude all directories from the `find` command target. I can use this:

```
find / -not -path /my/path -name name
```

But this still keep looking at all subdirectories of `/my/path`. Is there a way to exclude the directory and all its subdirectories from `find`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

with `-prune`

```
find . -name directory_to_exclude -prune -o ...
```

to exclude many directories

```
find . \( -name dir1_to_exclude -o -name dir2 ... \) -prune -o ...
```

Comment: The question is I tried `find / -name /proc -prune -o -print 2>/dev/null`. but it still prints lots of `/proc/1623` and so forth subdirectories. What's wrong?

Comment: Understood. Name does not work here. We need to use `-path`.

Comment: name works but can't have any `/` like `/proc` but `proc`